# Java, cannot find symbol and trouble extracting dataType from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    public class Packages 
    {
    private ArrayList shipmentList = new ArrayList();
    private double totalWeight;

    public Packages(String shiplist) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(shiplist));
        scanFile.useDelimiter("\n");
        while(scanFile.hasNext() == true){
            String pack = scanFile.next();
            Scanner splitter = new Scanner(pack);
            splitter.useDelimiter(" ");
            int id = splitter.nextInt();
            double weight = splitter.nextDouble();
            String state = splitter.next();
            shipmentList.add(new Packet(id, weight, state));
        }
        this.totalWeight = 0;

    }

    public String toString()
    {String allShipments ="";
    for(int i =0;i<shipmentList.size();i++)
        allShipments += shipmentList.get(i) + "\n";
    return allShipments;
    }
    //needs work. Cannot find method isLight() from class packet, yet toString() fires fine.
   public void displayLightPackages()
   {
    for (int i=0;i<shipmentList.size();i++){
       Packet thisShipment = shipmentList.get(i);
        if(thisShipment.isLight() == true){
            System.out.println("Package: "+ shipmentList.get(i).toString()+" Is light.");
        }else{
            System.out.print("");
        }
    }
}
```

Method displayLightPackages() is giving me errors. here is the packet class:

```
public class Packet
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int idNumber;
    private double weight;
    private String state;

    public Packet(int idNumber, double weight, String state)
    {
        this.idNumber= idNumber;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.state = state;
    }
    public boolean isHeavy()
    {
        return (weight>10);
    }  
    public boolean isLight()
    {
      return (weight<10);
    }  
    public String toString()
    {
       return "ID: "+idNumber+" WEIGHT: "+weight+" STATE: "+state;
    }
}
```

Method toString fires fine on a call from the main method, however, I cannot access any of the other methods from the Packet class. The constructor works when adding packets to the Arraylist containing all packets. I tried defining a packet in the displayLightPackages with

```
Packet thisShipment = shipmentList.get(i);
```

but I get an incompatible type error. When just using the code

```
shipmentList.get(i).isLight()
```

in the displayLightPackages method, I get an error where the compiler cannot find the symbol isLight. I suspect the error has something to do with the dataType in the arraylist, but other than that, i'm at a loss at this point.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ArrayList` isn't typed, so everything coming from it is an `Object`.  Conversely, `Object` doesn't have an `isLight()` method, hence the "cannot find symbol" error.

To solve this, either type your `ArrayList`...

```
private ArrayList<Packet> shipmentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

... or cast to `Packet` when you use `get`:

```
((Packet)shipmentList.get(i)).isLight()
```

Of the two options, typing the `ArrayList` is simpler and safer, since you don't have to remember to cast every time you're getting a value from it.

Comment: wow, thanks man. Completely solved my problem and I learned something! thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Change

`private ArrayList shipmentList = new ArrayList();`

to

`private ArrayList<Packet> shipmentList = new ArrayList<Packet>();`

Compiler does not know that shipmentList holds Packets. In fact, compiler know that shipmentList is a list of an Objects. So you are able to do `shipmentList.get(i).toString()`, because `toString()` is method from Object class. But you can't invoke `isLight()` method on `object` because it doesn't exists in `Object` context. You must explictly say that shipmentList is type of `ArrayList<Packet>`, or cast element to Packet: `Packet thisShipment = (Packet) shipmentList.get(i);`